# Dotnet install help required

Tags: .net, ubuntu

Could someone help me install dotnet? Ive followed a bunch of guides and this is the closest i seem to get.

```
ubuntu@xxx:~$ sudo apt-cache dump | grep dotnet-sdk
Package: dotnet-sdk-5.0:amd64
Package: dotnet-sdk-6.0:amd64
ubuntu@xxx:~$ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-5.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-5.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-5.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-5.0'
ubuntu@xxx:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption you've not done this, here are some additional actions to perform prior to installation, please see this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu

You'll likely need to follow these steps:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/21.04/packages-microsoft- 
prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb

sudo apt-get update; \
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

Comment: Doing this still seems to result in the same error

E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-5.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-5.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-5.0'